# Aggregate a boolean array in a LEFT JOIN LATERAL in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

**Question**

How can I achieve aggregation of the boolean array in the `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`?

A `result` can have many `owners`.

There can only by one `ownership` record that is `original` - that's because we are supporting the assignment of a `result` by the `original` `owner` to a new `owner`.

In this case, we would have two `ownership` records, differing in the `owner_id` as well as the `original` boolean value of the row.

---

**ERD**

*Note:* There is a small error in this ERD. The `owners` table has `id INT` and `owner UUID` (not just a single `id` column). This probably doesn't contribute to the issue - but it does make the SQL a little more gnarly than it should be.

[image: erd-results-ownership-owners]

**Results**

| guid | assigned |
| --- | --- |
| 061c840a-f8d2-4200-8d17-40b35650de40 | {true} |
| 074e3e67-c22a-4681-a5da-844b943a0cf9 | "{false,true}" |
| 084de451-6531-4997-b788-17819f29a6cb | {true} |

**Desired Results**

| guid | assigned |
| --- | --- |
| 061c840a-f8d2-4200-8d17-40b35650de40 | true |
| 074e3e67-c22a-4681-a5da-844b943a0cf9 | false |
| 084de451-6531-4997-b788-17819f29a6cb | true |

**SQL**

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (results.id) results.id as guid,
                                assigned
FROM results
         LEFT JOIN LATERAL ( SELECT *,
                                    (SELECT array(SELECT ownership.original
                                                  FROM ownership
                                                  where ownership.result_id = results.id)) as assigned
                             FROM (ownership
                                      LEFT JOIN owners on (ownership.owner_id = owners.id))) as resultOwnership
                   ON results.id = resultOwnership.result_id
WHERE resultOwnership.owner = '2a09be27-3fed-4c48-9c63-6877dddc95f5';
```

Comment: `true = all(assigned)`?

Comment: You did not state the actual objective of the query. "aggregation of the boolean array" is not an objective. Nor your version of Postgres.